# List in table cells in quill js

Tags: quill

I am looking for a way to make a list inside of a table cell with quill library. I've found some libraries for quill as [tableui](https://github.com/volser/quill-table-ui) and [quill-better-table](https://github.com/soccerloway/quill-better-table), but they doesn't provide such functionality. Are there any other libraries, that may help me?